# How to update multiple rows with Yii2 ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have 2 tables populated with values:

```
`users`
id | name | account_id | card_id

`cards` 
id | name | account_id
```

Now I need to get all values from `users`.`card_id` column, find all records from `cards` where `cards`.`id` = `users`.`card_id`, then take from these records from table `cards` values of `account_id` and update `users`.`account_id` with these values. Could you, please, show me the right way for this with Yii2 and Active Record?

My code:

```
class CodeController
{
    public function actionGo()
    {

    $cardsIdsFromUsers = Users::find()
        ->select('card_id')
        ->column();

    $accountsFromCards = Cards::find()
        ->where(['id' => $cardsIdsFromUsers])
        ->all();

    foreach($accountsFromCards as $account){
        $user = Users::find()
            ->where(['card_id' => $account->id])
            ->one();

        $user->account_id = $account->account_id;
        $user->update();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but there are 20k rows in both tables, and code works very slow. Also, I'm understand that that my code far far away from optimal, so please, provide advice how to make it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `createCommand()` method of `\yii\db\Connection` to create update over two tables like this

```php
$command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
    'UPDATE users, cards SET users.account_id = cards.account_id WHERE cards.id = users.card_id'
);
$command->execute();
```

This will only work properly if the relation between those two tables is 1:1.

But there are two question you should ask yourself:

1) Do you really need to save the account_id in both tables? Having redundancy in data is usually a bad idea because it invites some consistency problems.

2) Is it ok for account_id to be different for one card id in those two tables? If the account id should be always same then you should consider using [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). Triggers would update the other table when the account_id in one table is changed instead of updating all once in a while.

**UPDATE:** In comments below it has been clarified that tables are in different DBs on same MySQL server accessible with single DB user.

If the mysql user can access both tables you can do the UPDATE query over two tables that are in different dbs simply by prefixing the table names with database names. Assuming the connection in `Yii::$app->db` is set for user that can access both databases, the code will look like this:

```php
$command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
    'UPDATE db1.users, db2.cards SET users.account_id = cards.account_id WHERE cards.id = users.card_id'
);
$command->execute();
```

Note: db1 and db2 in SQL command should be replaced with actual names of databases that contais the tables.

Comment: thanks for the reply. These 2 tables (`users`, `cards`) are in different dbs. Is it possible to create command in this case? And is it possible to mass update with ActiveRecord?

Comment: @Dmitry are those 2 dbs in same mysql server or in different? Do you have db user that has permission for both of these dbs?

Comment: About mass update with ActiveRecord... The basic idea of active record design pattern is, that one instance of model represents 1 record of data that can be loaded and/or saved so it is not focused on mass manipulation of data. In yii2 there is `ActiveRecord::updateAll()` static method (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#updateAll()-detail) for updating multiple rows at once, but it is designed to update all records with same values so it won't be much useful in your case.

Comment: yes, both dbs in the same server and user has permissions.

Comment: @Dmitry I've updated the answer with the cross-db variant of command.

Comment: thank you! And what about `db` in $command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand? It needs to update for what db?

Comment: The `db` in `\Yii::$app->db->createCommand` is id of `yii\db\Connection` [component of Application](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#$db-detail). It depends on configuration of your application. You have to use the connection component, that is set for the user that has access to both databases.

Comment: In this app there are different users for each db. How can I create command in this case?

Comment: You can't. If single command is supposed to access tables in two DBs then that command must be executed by user that can access both of these tables. In that case the only way you can optimize your code is to use `User::updateAll(['account_id' => $account->account_id], ['card_id' => $account->id]);` inside your foreach cycle instead of loading each record and then saving it. But it will still be much slower then single command. So if you can create user that would be able to access both DBs you should do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!